# Check out accidently changed code git

Tags: git

Here's this scenario.

I had deleted a lot of files from my git.

They were always shown when I did `git status` as deleted

```
deleted:vendor/gems/spree_reviews1/bin/rails
```

It was also showing modified for `Gemfile.lock`.

I had to pull some changes from bitbucket so It asked me to do commit the local changes first. But since I had not made any changes I simply did `git stash` to ignore that and then again did `git pull`, But for some reason, all the app files are now showing as in create mode.

I am not sure what's wrong here.

Can someone help me go back to the old scenario where all the files were showing deleted when I did `git status`.

Comment: the commits you recently pulled may have deleted those files.  But if those files were deleted and committed, they should've been deleted when you git pulled. Sorry, not really helpful.

Comment: share your `git log` information here.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `git stash` your changes including deleted files stashed away and working directory reverted to HEAD commit.
To return stashed modifications use `git stash apply`.
If you have stashed modifications several times use `git stah list` to display stashes you have and then `git stash apply stash@{2}` where 2 is stash for example.